# How to find the number of pills which someone has consumed given a time range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The problem is as follows:

> Marina went to the doctor and he has advised her to take vitamins. As
>   doctor's orders she has to take one tablet of Vitamin C every 6 hours.
>   From vitamin D she has to take two pills every 8 hours and from
>   vitamin K, three pills every 9 hours. It is known from her diary that
>   she took 330 pills in total and began taking the three kinds at the
>   same time. During how many hours, the least, did she took the pills?

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{504 hours}\\
2.&\textrm{360 hours}\\
3.&\textrm{432 hours}\\
4.&\textrm{288 hours}\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly how to tackle this problem, can someone help me?. The suggested approach which I was given in class is that the number of doses that a person takes is equal to:

$dose=\frac{\textrm{total time}}{\textrm{time for each or unit time}}+1$

which I think it kind of makes sense, but I don't know how to use that formula and why?. Can someone help me using this approach? The part where I'm confused is exactly how should I understand the word which was given that say *the least*?. How is this translated in the problem?.

Comment: The question asks about "How many hours" but the choices available are "Pills". I am confused.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Sorry, I'm already fixing any discrepancy.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 The alternatives were read as hours. I fixed it already. Should be understood.

Comment: "The least" just means that there are many possible hours that fit the criteria and you are to find the smallest of them.

Answer (score 1):

The number of pills she takes in $n$ hours is:

$$6 + \left \lceil{\frac{n}{6}}\right \rceil +  2\cdot \left\lceil{\frac{n}{8}}\right \rceil + 3 \cdot \left \lceil{\frac{n}{9}}\right \rceil $$

where $\left \lceil{x} \right\rceil $ is the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \leq n$.

This is because at the start, when $n=0$, she takes $6$ pills. Then she takes one every $6$ hours, two every $8$ hours and three every $9$ hours.

That being said, you want to solve 
$$6 + \left \lceil{\frac{n}{6}}\right \rceil +  2\cdot \left\lceil{\frac{n}{8}}\right \rceil + 3 \cdot \left \lceil{\frac{n}{9}}\right \rceil = 330 $$

If we drop the $\lceil{\;}\rceil$, we have to solve (I multiplied by $12$ to remove fractions)

$$12 \cdot 6 + 2n + 3n + 4n = 12 \cdot 330$$

$$9n = 3888$$

which gives $n=432$. Is this the smallest $n$? Well, let's check:

$$\frac{432}{6} = 72 \; , \; \frac{432}{8} = 54 \; , \; \frac{432}{9} = 48$$

All integers! So if you lower $n$ by one, you lower the values of each $\left \lceil{\frac{n}{x}}\right \rceil$ for $x=6,8,9$, and therefore the expression above is not equal to $330$ anymore.

Comment: This doesn't use the formula which I have been advised to use isn't it?. Or it does use it?. Does it mean that the total number of pills taken will be equal to just adding the quantities mentioned times the fraction of $\frac{pill}{time}$ and equating this to the total number of pills? But how can I guarantee that's the smallest?. I think that it makes sense that I'm talking and thinking that I cannot split the pills (which is kind of contradictory because you **can** actually do that. But I think in this given context you aren't allowed to do so. Anyways you justify it

Comment: by saying that lowering the $n$ will not produce 330 pills. But perhaps does it exist a different way to justify it?.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Marina takes six pills initially.  After that, she takes $12 \cdot 1 + 9 \cdot 2 + 8 \cdot 3 = 54$ pills every $72$ hours.